# Plotly JavaScript Heatmap - hover text on X and Y field names (not data) on chart - want users to see categorical data definitions

Tags: javascript, html, plotly, heatmap, plotly.js

I've created a heatmap that looks at different types of projects by which categorical domain they fit in (geographical, temporal, digital, cultural, 'financial.'  Because they can be interpreted in many different ways, users have asked that we provide a hover over/tooltips text definition for each of these when someone hovers over the fieldname.  For example, when someone hovers over "Geographical" on the x axis field names, it would say something like "Definition: A project that is focused on distance, location, or proximity." I've provided a picture to be extra clear about what I mean by x axis field names.

**Bottom Line**: I want to know how to provide custom text when someone hovers over the x axis fieldname so I can define each fieldname. I could not find documentation for this.

EDIT: I realize this just *might* not be possible with Plotly. I appreciate any other ideas for easily allowing users to see the definitions for the domains.  Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
    <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>

    <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>

<script>


var data = [
  {

    z: [[8, 8, 7, 5, 7], [10, 5, 2, 11, 4], [6, 1, 2, 3, 1]],
    x: ['Geographical', 'Temporal', 'Cultural', 'Digital', 'Financial'],
    y: ['Observational', 'Program Evaluation', 'Intervention'],
    type: 'heatmap',

    hovertemplate: '<b># of %{y} Projects with a %{x} classification</b>: %{z}' + '<extra></extra>',

    hoverongaps: true
  }
];

var layout = {
  title: 'Domains by Project Type',
  width: 900,
  height: 625,
  autosize: false,
    yaxis: {automargin: true}
};

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data, layout);
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: This is not a trivial task as Plotly doesn't provide a way to do this and the method is elaborated as the tick labels on the X axis are behind other Plotly controls (drag handles). Also, the tick labels are SVG g.text elements which don't have width or height, thus you can't associate mouse events to them. You would need to programmatically get their position & dimensions and trigger your tooltip logic manually from an invisible surface over the labels. I've been coding using Plotly for years and gave up.

Comment: I was worried someone would say that, but I hoped that wasn't the case.  Guess this is trickier than I expected.

Comment: If you still want to do this, it might be easier to use a different plotting library and JavaScript the mouse events manually. Plotly's DOM structure is way more complex than the alternatives so with a different lib you might be able to point a JS tooltip library directly to a selector for the tick labels. In any case, this will require coding.